# Servlet exception when trying to open it

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I programmed a servlet that should print out 'Hello World', but it is not working correctly.

I start tomcat by running the `startup.sh` in `/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/startup.sh` and my program is in the folder `/usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/hello/WEB-INF/classes/HelloWorld.class`.

This is my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is my source code:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet
{

    static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                  HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException
    {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("\t<title>Test</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<b>Hello World!</b>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

I compile it with the following command:

```
javac -classpath %J2EE_HOME%\lib\j2ee.jar -classpath ../../../../lib/servlet-api.jar HelloWorld.java
```

There are no compiling errors, but when I visit `ipaddress:8080/hello/HelloWorld` I get following errorcode:

```
exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.binaryNameToPath(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2562)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findLoadedClass0(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2730)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1208)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: You should build a war file and put it in the webapps Folder instead of putting it manually

Comment: @Jens hey, can you explain what you mean with 'war file'?

Comment: @BalusC here you go mate, no need to be upset https://www.anavi.org/article/20/

Comment: you need a servlet container to start your servlet, then it can respond the invocation.

Comment: @CaptainTreibholz BalusC seems to be in especially sarcastic mood today, but he is basically right. As the local [documentation effort](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/servlets/2857/introduction-to-servlets) for servlets has just started, I would recommend to get the [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html), or, if you use Eclipse and want some shortcut, [this one](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseWTP/article.html) from Lars Vogel.